# Golang https certificate error: remote error: tls: unknown certificate authority

Tags: firefox, go, self-signed

I have made my cert and key using the following

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -new -nodes -x509 -days 3650 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem
```

And configured it in my Golang code

```
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServeTLS(":4201", "cert.pem", "key.pem", router))
```

It worked well when accessing using chrome but it throws the error on the console when accessing using firefox.

> 2018/03/02 16:54:11 http: TLS handshake error from 100.67.56.121:54397: remote error: tls: unknown certificate authority

How can I solve the issue?

Comment: Two options: Use a recognized signing authority, or configure Firefox to recognize the authority you're using. Neither of these tasks is really on-topic here. For the latter, SuperUser would probably be the best place to ask (although I'm sure Google can already tell you).

Comment: Any way I can control on server side? As it's not possible to ask everyone to configure Firefox on their side. I tried below but with no luck.  http.DefaultTransport.(*http.Transport).TLSClientConfig = &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true}
  log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServeTLS(":4201", "cert.pem", "key.pem", router))

Comment: Yes. As I said, you can use a certificate with a recognized authority on the server side.

Comment: No, you cannot configure servers to tell clients to blindly trust them. That would defeat the whole point of TLS. If your server is publicly accessible or you control the DNS entries, you can get a trustworthy certificate for free from https://letsencrypt.org.

Answer (score 8):

"Remote error" means error sent from client (firefox in this case).

Solution is to figure out why firefox doesn't like the certificate and fix it.

There is something that firefox doesn't like about the certificate.  Open up firefox dev tools and see if you can find any warnings regarding the certificate.  If you had to manually accept the certificate in Firefox then it is possible that Firefox is still reporting to the server that it doesn't like the certificate even though you have told firefox to load the page anyway (see chrome example below).

However as this is a self generated/signed certificate the warning is probably because firefox doesn't trust this certificate.  Solution is to either add this certificate to firefox's trusted certificates if this server is only for your own personal use...or to get a certificate signed by a commercial CA or letsencrypt.

"Fixing this server-side" means fixing whatever it is about how your certificate/app is served in order to make it trusted by firefox.  Or I suppose ignoring the errors if you are just doing development.

**More details...**

Key thing here is that this is a "remote error" meaning it is an error from the tls CLIENT connecting to your server.  In your case it is Firefox complaining during the TLS handshake that the certificate is invalid in some way.

I noticed the same thing with chrome.  Cert is signed by a public CA (ie a CA that should be trusted by most browsers) but as I am developing on my local machine, the certificate is invalid because hostname (localhost) doesn't match the certificate CommonName (CN) or Subject Alternative Names (SAN).

Easiest thing to do is just look at the TLS handshake in wireshark.

[image: wireshark handshake capture]

I told chrome to accept the certificate, started capture and did a SINGLE refresh of the page (https://localhost:8081 in this case).  Chrome does not present me with a warning page and shows the content.  There is a red warning in the address bar however.

The interesting thing (to me) is that it appears (I'm no TLS expert) that there are two TLS handshakes.

Client Hello
Server Hello
Alert (client error)
Client Hello
Server Hello
Client complete handshake
...encrypted application data...

Since chrome doesn't interrupt my refresh of the page I am not sure why chrome does the handshake twice (first time with Alert/failure) for a single page refresh.

The interesting bit I learned here (obvious in hindsight) is that it is possible to get reporting from browsers/clients when they reject your certificate. This can be used on the server side (if monitored) to discover subtle certificate mis-configurations in production that your test cases might not cover.  Unfortunately as this is pre-http you won't get user-agent or anything useful to help with reproducing....but a large number of these errors as a percentage of server traffic indicates you need to do some serious cross browser/os/device testing

Comment: Not an expert, perhaps the reason you get two handshakes is because the server did not receive acceptable options from the first handshake since you are using a self-signed cert.

"4.1.4.  Hello Retry Request
   The server will send this message in response to a ClientHello
   message if it is able to find an acceptable set of parameters but the
   ClientHello does not contain sufficient information to proceed with
   the handshake.  As discussed in Section 4.1.3, the HelloRetryRequest
   has the same format as a ServerHello message"

https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8446#section-4.1.4